# Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a page where I have to display the total count of 7 collections .
And if any new item is created in a collection, then my page should show the updated count. I tried as follows

```
this.listenTo(XyzCollection, 'update', function() {
  self.lengthVariable = XyzCollection.length;
  self.render();
});
```

The problem with this approach is, if the count of any collection is huge(say 1000), then the render method is getting called that many times(and there are total 7 collections to be called).

I also tried

```
this.listenTo(XyzCollection, 'update', function() {
    self.lengthVariable = XyzCollection.length;
    //self.render();
});
```

i.e. just update the variable, but page dose'nt get refreshed and on the template i see the counts as 0(I commented out render).

Please suggest a proper way to achieve the scenario

the example initialize and render of view are as follows:

```
initialize: function() {
    xxx1Collection.refresh();
    xxx2Collection.refresh();
    xxx3Collection.refresh();
    xxx4Collection.refresh();
    xxx5Collection.refresh();
    xxx6Collection.refresh();
    xxx7Collection.refresh();

    var self = this;

    this.listenTo(xxx1Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var1 = xxx1Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });

    this.listenTo(xxx2Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var2 = xxx2Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });

    this.listenTo(xxx3Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var3 = xxx3Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });

    this.listenTo(xxx4Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var4 = xxx4Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });  

    this.listenTo(xxx5Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var5 = xxx5Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });

    this.listenTo(xxx6Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var6 = xxx6Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });

    this.listenTo(xxx7Collection, 'update', function() {
        self.var7 = xxx4Collection.length;
        self.render();
    });
},

render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template({
        count1: self.var1,
        count2: self.var2,
        count3: self.var3,
        count4: self.var4,
        count5: self.var5,
        count6: self.var6,
        count7: self.var7,
    }));
```

}

Comment: Where are you adding thise listener? Looks like you're adding it multiple times otherwise it shouldn't be getting called that many times. Please provide [mcve]

Comment: I am adding the listener in the initialize method, and for each collection(7), i am adding the listener, to update seven variables for each collection respectively

Comment: `initialize` of what? A router? A view? A Base view of other views? How many instances of these exists? `XyzCollection` is a Collection constructor or instance? (The case is suspicious) We need more information to help you. We can't figure out the problem if you say hey I do this in initialize and I'm getting unexpected behavior. We need to see what you're doing to figure out the actual cause behind the unexpected behavior...

Comment: in the initialize of view , i call the collections ...There is only one view, which should call the 7 collections, so that is gets the counts to be passed onto the template.. Xyz is a collection instance (i import it into the view to make use of it ). similarly in the initialize of view...i have 6 more calls to 6 different collections ...i hope its clear now ...

Comment: Maybe at least post the entire initialize method that's handling these 7 collections. Words are very unlikely to help anyone solve the problem

Comment: Backbone collections do not have a `.refresh` method... You probably have custom code like that which is causing the error. Maybe try creating an [mcve]

Comment: refresh() is a custom function which just resets the collection and fetches entire data again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137672/discussion-between-sk215-and-t-j).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there's a good reason for 7 collections *with incremental names* to exist in a view, the simplest way to re-render on collection update is the following.

```
initialize: function() {
    // make collections properties of the view
    this.xxx1Collection.refresh();
    this.xxx2Collection.refresh();
    /* ... */
    this.xxx7Collection.refresh();

    // create the event hash once, and reuse it.
    var events = { update: this.render };

    // there's no need to use `self` when using `this.listenTo`
    this.listenTo(this.xxx1Collection, events)
        .listenTo(this.xxx2Collection, events)
        /* ... */
        .listenTo(this.xxx7Collection, events);
},

render: function() {
    // just pass the length here instead.
    this.$el.html(this.template({
        count1: this.xxx1Collection.length,
        count2: this.xxx2Collection.length,
        /* ... */
        count7: this.xxx7Collection.length,
    }));
}
```

From the [Catalog of Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog):

> **"update"** `(collection, options)` — single event triggered after any
>   number of models have been added or removed from a collection.

Comment: @TJ the problem comes from somewhere else, not shown in the question.

Comment: Yes then how is the answer to question... ;)

Comment: @TJ It answers with the simplest way to re-render on update, confirming that it should work like that. OP can now look elsewhere to find the problem.

Comment: "Your code should work, look elsewhere" should be a comment + close vote, not answer imo... ("the problem comes from somewhere else, not shown in the question" being the reason for close vote)

Comment: @TJ _"It answers with the **simplest way** to re-render on update"_, it's also additional information on the `update` event and basic JavaScript which would have been too long for a comment. Comments serve to ask for clarification (which you did already). Showing a working example is a valid way to answer a question or at least help get closer to the solution OP is looking for.